# What should I use for a python program to do stuff with tables of data?

Tags: python, database

I want to be able to add daily info to each object and want to have the ability to delete info x days old easily. With the tables I need to look at the trends and do stuff like selecting objects which match some criteria.

Edit: I asked this because I'm not able to think of a way to implement deleting old data easily because you cannot delete tables in sqlite

Comment: What kind of database is it in?

Comment: As the FAQ states, You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Please reflect this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sqlite would it be the best option, is file based, easy to use, you can use Lookups with SQL and it's builtin on python you don't need to install anything.

→ http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

If your question means that you are just going to be using "table like data" but not bound to a db, look into using this python modul: [Module for table like snytax](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286192-table-objects-with-operations-in-sql-like-syntax/)

If you are going to be binding to a back end, and not* distributing your data among computers, then SQLite is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A "proper" database would probably be the way to go. If your application only runs on one computer and the database doesn't get to big, sqlite is good and easy to use with python (standard module sqlite3, see the Library Reference for more information)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the sqlite3 module, it lets you create a single-file database (no server to setup) that will let you perform sql queries. It's part of the standard library in python, so you don't need to install anythin additional.

http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html